# “Featured” status not working

Tags: status, dynamic

We faced a weird issue with **status="Featured"** for our channel entry tag today, when we changed the custom status of our health topic channel entry from "Featured" to "Closed", and created a new health topic channel entry with the status="Featured". This process has worked in the past, but doesn't seem to work today.

The tag looks like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="health_topics" limit="1" status="Featured" dynamic="no"}
//HTML code
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Nothing is displayed is the sections with the above snippet.
This issue is common to another channel "Event".

What could be the issue? 
Any assistance is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the date of the entry? Is it on future?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the date of entry, and it is not set to a future date.

Comment: Are you using any sort of caching mechanisms? EE has tag caching and template caching, or there could be some upstream caches like memcache or APC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. The problem is actually due to caching. Turned off 'Cache Dynamic Channel Queries' in the global channel preferences and now the results are coming up.
I did try clearing all cache before I did that and it made no difference, so I believe there was a problem with file/folder permissions. It's similar to the error when we try to write to the cache folder and I noticed a similar error saving templates (when it tries to save templates to files).
There was a cache file for that URL, EE couldn't clear the cache file, so it kept being used to figure if there were any matching results and coming back 'no'.
Thanks everyone for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

First things first, have you double checked your Status Group assignment in Channel Groups?

`Admin -> Channel Administration -> Channels -> Edit Group Assignments`

Sorry if you have checked this, you don't mention anything about your Status group setup and it's always good to start at the start!

Comment: Yes, I have checked the status group assignment. No issues with that.

Comment: Have you resaved the entries? What happens if u use `status="NOT featured'` ?